# Order NSArray of Dictionaries - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries that looks something like this

```
({order:1; name:foo},{order:0; name:bar}...)
```

And I want to order this `NSArray` of dictionaries by the key "order".

I know I am going to have to loop though it and then add it to a new array but Im not quite sure how to set it up?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible ways to do this.

Here's one:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = ... // your unsorted array of dictionaries
NSSortDescriptor *sortBy = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortBy ]];
```

Here's another:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = ... // your unsorted array of dictionaries
NSArray *sorted = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dic1, NSDictionary *dic2) {
    NSNumber *order1 = dic1[@"order"];
    NSNumber *order2 = dic2[@"order"];

    return [order1 compare:order2];
}];
```